# Open new konsole from script, executing command and becoming interactive on conclusion

Tags: bash, automation, konsole, interactive

I want to be able to get a script (ran at startup) to open up a `konsole` terminal.
When it opens it is to do some persistent things (like change directory and source bashrc) and run a long running program.
If the program crashes or I come in and `<ctrl+c>` it, it is to start accepting commands from standard input (like 'up-enter' to try again, as if it was interactive the whole time).

I have tried so many things to get it working (I'm currently just trying to get it to `ls` and revert to interactive on completion);

```
konsole -e ls
konsole --hold ls
konsole -e /bin/bash -c ls
konsole --hold -e "/bin/bash -c ls"
konsole -e "/bin/bash -i -c ls"
konsole -e /bin/bash -i -c ls
konsole -e "echo ls > /tmp/konsolebash;/bin/bash -i --rcfile /tmp/konsolebash"

echo ls > /tmp/konsolebash
konsole -e "/bin/bash -i --rcfile /tmp/konsolebash"
```

Is it to do with the quotes? Should I not be using them, should I be escaping something?
Am I even meant to try and execute `bash`?
I'm running out of ideas but I hope it's even achievable (but hopefully not something embarrassingly simple that I missed).

I'll upvote answers that successfully use other terminal emulators if `konsole` in particular is the problem (but since the question is specifically about `konsole` I don't think I can give you the juicy tick)

Comment: The last two lines look promising. Have you tried them without escaping the quotes around `source ... ls`?

Comment: sorry that was a copy paste error from writing the question

Comment: And that didn't work? Strange... What exactly *did* it do?

Comment: yeah it just brings up a normal interactive shell (no command is visibly ran, just prompt is displayed). It seems to either accept arguments, or be interactive, never both.

Comment: If nothing else works, you could use `konsole -e "bash -c 'ls'; bash"` -- which is really ugly, but should leave you with an interactive shell when `ls` terminates.

Comment: but that would forget any `cd` and command history (break `up-enter`). Might as well not not make it interactive and open two shells

Comment: Since we're already doing ugly things: `ls; echo 'ls' >> $HOME/.bash_history; bash`

Comment: I still think however that using `--rcfile` should have done exactly what you need... Edit: In fact, I just checked and `bash --rcfile /tmp/foo` does work for me, while `bash` refuses to start with `-i --rcfile /tmp/foo`. So try omitting the `-i` and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that commands in the rcfile are not added to the history, so `--rcfile` is useless for your application. Looks like we'll need the `echo 'ls' >> .bash_history` hack after all...

Comment: And here's yet another idea, suggested by ZyX in a comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6219428/1114687): invoke a `screen` session, then have it run `ls` in the newly created session.

Comment: thanks for all this, I didn't know it'd be this hard. The comment I upvoted worked (without history though). Even if a `cd` is in the file. You should make an answer so I can upvote it/so others can see it and get help from it too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @n.st's comments I have made this one liner:

```sh
konsole -e /bin/bash --rcfile <(echo "cd /;ls;echo hi | less")
```

Which is just a shorter version without tmpfiles, using bash process substitution for the following;

```sh
echo "cd /;ls;echo hi | less" > /tmp/konsolebash;konsole -e /bin/bash --rcfile /tmp/konsolebash
```

Which will run some commands, have them display, change the environment, run a long running program (`less`) and when it ends (`:q`) will be interactive.
So replace `cd /;ls;echo hi | less` (the demonstration) with your script.

No history but at least you're in the correct directory now and have any environment variables you may have wanted set up.

---

Basically the same as my prior attempt;

```sh
konsole -e "echo ls > /tmp/konsolebash;/bin/bash -i --rcfile /tmp/konsolebash"
```

except the file write is outside the `konsole` execution, I've dropped the `-i` flag and the execution parameters are not in one quote block

---

Unfortunately the `--rcfile` switch causes your `~/.bashrc` not to be loaded for those commands, so if you needed an alias or something you'll have to do this;

```sh
cat ~/.bashrc > /tmp/konsolebash; echo "commands" >> /tmp/konsolebash;konsole -e /bin/bash --rcfile /tmp/konsolebash
```

Which just copies your bashrc then *appends* your commands to the end of it

Comment: There is no need to copy your bashrc, just use `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I actually tried that, it doesn't work for the rest of the commands in the list. I.e if `.bashrc` has alias `BOB`, the argument `source ~/.bashrc;BOB;cd /` will have `BOB` fail. I have no idea why, but this works

Answer (score 1):

A shorter & simpler solution:

```
konsole -e '$SHELL -c "ls; $SHELL"' &
```

This one doesn't have the issues with history or sourcing `.bashrc` either.
If your `$SHELL` environment variable doesn't point to bash, you can specify it manually.

This does spawn a second (bash) shell inside the same terminal window, so some things from the first command might not be carried over.

Answer adapted from an askubuntu [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1210210/307091).